# GDAL Error in CreateCopy: in method 'Driver_CreateCopy', argument 3 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'

Tags: gdal

I'm working on a simple script using GDAL Driver.CreateCopy function, but I keep getting the same error.
The script is very basic:

```
import os,arcpy,sys
from osgeo import gdal

source_folder=r'E:\to_conv'
conv_folder='E:\conv'
compression_type='JPEG'
compression_quality='70'

arcpy.env.workspace=source_folder
rasters=arcpy.ListRasters("*","TIF")
for raster in rasters:
    tiff_file=os.path.join(conv_folder,raster)
    source_file=os.path.join(source_folder,raster)
    print(source_file)
    try:
        dformat="GTiff"
        driver = gdal.GetDriverByName( dformat )
        metadata = driver.GetMetadata()
        if metadata.has_key(gdal.DCAP_CREATE) and metadata[gdal.DCAP_CREATE] == 'YES':
            print 'Driver %s supports Create() method.' % dformat
        if metadata.has_key(gdal.DCAP_CREATECOPY) and metadata[gdal.DCAP_CREATECOPY] == 'YES':
            print 'Driver %s supports CreateCopy() method.' % dformat
        src_ds = gdal.Open(source_file)
        dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(tiff_file,source_file, options=["ALPHA=YES"] )
    except Exception:
        e=sys.exc_info()[1]
        print ("Error converting "+ source_file + " to " + tiff_file + ": " +str(e))
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
E:\to_conv\testfile1.tif  
Driver GTiff supports Create() method.  
Driver GTiff supports CreateCopy() method.  
Error converting E:\to_conv\testfile1.tif to E:\conv\testfile1.tif: in method 'Driver_CreateCopy', argument 3 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
```

Any help ?

Comment: What is the meaning of "0" in `dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(tiff_file,source_file, 0)`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove the ) after a test I did, the correct line is dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(tiff_file,source_file, 0,
                                       [ "TILED=YES", "COMPRESS="+compression_type, "JPEG_QUALITY="+compression_quality] )

Comment: and strictly speaking this is the bStrict parameter: TRUE if the copy must be strictly equivalent, or more normally FALSE indicating that the copy may adapt as needed for the output format.

Comment: The syntax used in GDAL autotests https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gcore/tiff_write.py seems to be `gdaltest.tiff_drv.CreateCopy('/vsimem/rgb_added_alpha.tif', ds, options=['ALPHA=YES'])`.

Comment: I changed the line to  dst_ds = driver.CreateCopy(tiff_file,source_file, source= [ "TILED=YES", "COMPRESS="+compression_type, "JPEG_QUALITY="+compression_quality] ), same error

Comment: Please read it again and pay attention to "options=".

Comment: Sorry, I changed to "options=" and still same error

Comment: Try just copy-paste options=['ALPHA=YES']. If it works consider if your "COMPRESS="+compression_works as you suppose.

Comment: Done, still same error!

Comment: Odd. Could you please update your question so that it is up to date with your current trials? Strict=false is the default so you can drop it, I guess.